# Repeat capturing group of comma seperated key value pairs

Tags: regex, optimization, pcre

I'm currently trying to extract the following from patterns like `@Apple(kind="Bax", priority=33)`

- Apple
- [kind, Bax], [priority, 33]

What I currently use is `@([^(]*)\(([^\)]*)\)`. Then I have `Apple` and `kind="Bax", priority=33`. After this, I split group 2 on `,`, then split on `=` and finally remove `"` if any at start or end.

Now this will traverse the second segment a lot. First for the regex capture, then to find all `,`, then for each traverse again to find `=` etc etc.

Since I do this millions of times, is there any way to capture it withing the regex traversal? I'd like to avoid all the splits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to allow the count of key=value pairs to be arbitrary length, how about:

```
(?:@|\(|,\s*|="?)(\w+)(?=\(|=|"|,|\))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/F1EpEr/1)

All captures are in Group 1.

- `(?:@|\(|,\s*|="?)` matches one of `@`, `(`, `,` plus whitespaces more than 0,
  or `=` plus an optional `"`.
- `(\w+)` matches the desired word and is captured in Group1.
- `(?=\(|=|"|,|\))` is a positive lookahead assertion to match one of `(`,
  `=`, `"`, `,` or `)`.

**[Edit]**

If the element enclosed by the double quotes may contain a comma, It will not be easy to parse it with a single regex.
If possible,
it will be less maintenable. I would divide the operation in two steps.
Suppose we have a string:

```
@Apple(val="a,b", kind="Bax", priority=33,foo=bar, name="John Doe", lorem=ipsum)
```

Then with the 1st regex:

```
^@([^(]+)\(([^)]+)\)
```

`Apple` is captured in Group 1 and the substring enclosed in the parentheses is
captured in Group 2.

Then apply the next regex to the Group 2:

```
(?<=")[^"=]+(?=")|[^,=" ]+
```

Now we can obtain the list:

```
['val', 'a,b', 'kind', 'Bax', 'priority', '33', 'foo', 'bar', 'name', 'John Doe', 'lorem', 'ipsum']
```

[Demo of the 2nd regex](https://regex101.com/r/AsTUeT/1)

Comment: Very nice, I guess it's not easily possible that "..." could also contain a ","? Like @Test(val="a,b")?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yeah, I suppose it will not be easy to support
the case that "..." contains a comma *with a single regex*. I've updated my answer with the 2-stage version, although I'm not sure if it meets your requirements. BR.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating 5 different capturing groups and use them accordingly, you need not to use split then. Please try following regex.

```
^@([^(]*)\(([^=]*)="(.*?)",\s+([^=]*)=([^)]*)\)
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/ND4BWP/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^@        ##Matching starting @ here in value.
([^(]*)   ##Creating 1st capturing group which has everything till ( here.
\(        ##Matching literal ( here.
([^=]*)   ##Creating 2nd capturing group which has everything till - here.
="        ##Matching =" here.
(.*?)     ##Creating 3rd capturing group here, which is a lazy match till next match.
",\s+     ##Matching ", followed by spaces 1 or more occurrences.
([^=]*)   ##Creating 4th capturing group which has everything till = here.
=         ##Matching = here.
([^)]*)\) ##Creating 5th capturing group which has everything till ) here, then matching literal ) here.
```

Comment: Once OP confirms this is working fine, then will add detailed explanation for it.

Comment: Great solution @RavinderSingh13, i really love that. A question, why the `?` in `(.*?)` don't `*` match zero to unlimited, making the `?` redundant?

Comment: @NilsKähler, Thank you. `?` it's actually denotes lazy match where .* Will be greedy one.

Comment: This will not work with variable length right? Like 10 attributes instead of two

Comment: @Regyn, yeah, it was given as per shown samples. Could you please show a sample of line which you are saying for better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Imagine an unlimited amount of parameters, like @Apple(kind="Bax", priority=33. a=1, b=3, t=3, t=454444)

Answer (score 1):

Another option might be making use of the `\G` anchor to get iterative matches for the part between the parenthesis, and match a variable number of parameters.

The value after the @ is in group 1, the keys and values between the parenthesis are in group 2 and 3

```
(?:@(\w+)\((?=[^()]*\))|\G(?!^))([^\s=]+)=(?|"([^"*"]*)"|([^\s,]+))(?:,\h*)?
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `@(\w+)` Match @ and capture 1+ word chars in **group 1**
  - `\((?=[^()]*\))` Match `(` and assert a closing `)` to the right
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, but not at the start (the anchor matches at 2 positions which can also be at the start of the string)
- `)` Close the group
- `([^\s=]+)=` Capture **group 2**, match any char except = or a whitespace char and then match `=`
- `(?|` Branch reset group

  - `"([^"*"]*)"|([^\s,]+)` capture **group 3**, capture either what is between double quotes or 1+ non whitespace chars without a comma
- `)(?:,\h*)?` close branch reset group and optionally match a comma and spaces

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bcXYUi/1)

Answer (score -1):

`@(\w+)\((\s*\w+="?\w+"?,?)*\)`

This regex assumes a variable number of arguments. However one limitation of regex is that **you should have a constant number of capture group**: so you will only capture last argument.

This regex below use a finite number of arguments (2) and a finite number of capture group (3)

`@(\w+)\((\s*\w+="?\w+"?,?)(\s*\w+="?\w+"?,?)\)`
(note: I've simply doubled the argument capture for the sake of demonstration)